# What's the difference between DoCmd.SetWarnings and CurrentDB.Execute

Tags: sql, ms-access, error-handling, vba

In the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11210977/190829), Remou writes that

`CurrentDB.Execute "insert sql here"`

is better than

`DoCmd.SetWarnings = 0

DoCmd.RunSQL "insert sql here"`

due to the built-in warnings that Access produces. I'm trying to understand the difference.

If they both mask errors, why is the first one preferable over the second? Are there any best practices here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They do not both mask errors. DoCmd.SetWarnings masks errors and is system wide, not confined to the single application that you are using. `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` without the corresponding  `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` will mean that action queries will run without any prompts in any Access application on the PC.

Execute does throw warnings, the warnings that you need, such as the query failed to execute, but does not give warnings you may not need, such as "Are you sure you want to run this query".

[In this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/198156-check-status-setwarnings) Allen Browne, Access MVP, says he does not use Set Warnings.

As an aside, I would generally recommend using an instance of CurrentDB, as this will allow you to return a record count, amongst other things, so:

```
Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: From your comment: `To run without the built-in warnings, use an instance of CurrentDB and Exceute the SQL string` which leads me to believe that `.Execute` does not throw warnings?

Comment: The more it is said, the better. It can be hard to get across to people how lethal SetWarnings can be.