# Writing to multiple columns simulatenously with SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am having trouble writing a VBA macro within Microsoft Access.  What I am trying to do is use SQL to create an output table, but I want to write to multiple columns simultaneously.

This gets me all the values I need for one column:

```
Docmd.RunSQL “INSERT INTO Output (TargetCol1) SELECT [Field1] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Criteria1] = ‘Value’ GROUP BY Field1”
```

When I try to run this multiple times to get the values I need for other columns.  INSERT INTO writes the data as new records, so I end up with blank spaces, like this:

```
Field1----Field2
Value----<Null>
Value----<Null>
Value----<Null>
<Null>----Value
<Null>----Value
```

What I want is:

```
Field1----Field2
Value---- Value
Value---- Value
Value----<Null>
```

I tried to create variables and create kind of a nested statement but I receive a ‘Compile error, object required’ on my first line when I try to run what I have written:

```
Set x = Docmd.RunSQL “INSERT INTO Output (TargetCol1) SELECT [Field1] FROM [Table1] WHERE      [Criteria1] = ‘Value’ GROUP BY Field1”
Set y = Docmd.RunSQL “INSERT INTO Output (TargetCol2) SELECT [Field2] FROM [Table1] WHERE  [Criteria2] = ‘Value’ GROUP BY Field2”
Docmd.runsql “INSERT INTO Output (TargetCol1, TargetCol2) Values (x,y)”
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
INSERT INTO Output (TargetCol1,TargetCol2) SELECT [Field1,Field2] FROM [Table1]  [Criteria1] = 'Value'"
```

Set is used for objects, and you do not have one in `Set x = Docmd.RunSQL`. Order by is irrelevant for a table.

The easiest way to set up queries is using the query design window. it will guide you through creating the query and you can then switch to SQL view to get SQL.

I suggest you do not use RunSQL : [What's the difference between DoCmd.SetWarnings and CurrentDB.Execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a response.  I get an 'Error number of query values and destination values are not the same.'

The GROUP BY is there to eliminate redundant values.

I'm checking out your link now.  Always trying to learn how do write better code.

Comment: Oops, I read Order By for Group By. I am by no means sure what you are trying to do here. Does the output table have more than one column? Do wish to update the second column, if so, you need something to join on? `Insert Into` always adds new records.

Comment: You gave me an idea to create separate tables for each output column, assign a unique ID, and then join the tables together.  Thank you.