# Can't set field value in Access form with new record

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I open my access form *ActivityTracker* to a new record, I want it to auto-populate the field *start_time* with the current time now().

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(Form_ActivityEntry.Start_time) And IsNull(Form_ActivityEntry.id) Then
        Form_ActivityEntry.Start_time = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

This throws an error "You can't assign a value to this object" and stops execution.

I can fix the error by going explicitly to a new record

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(Form_ActivityEntry.Start_time) And IsNull(Form_ActivityEntry.id) Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
        Form_ActivityEntry.Start_time = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

or by

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(Form_ActivityEntry.Start_time) And IsNull(Form_ActivityEntry.id) Then
        Me.Recordset.AddNew
        Form_ActivityEntry.Start_time = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

but either of these causes a popup warning, "You can't go to the specified record."

I've tried to suppress the warning with this

```
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

or by setting up error handling,

```
    On Error GoTo Err_SomeName
```

but I still get the warning.

AllowAdditions is set to True. Recordset type is Dynaset.

Otherwise, everything works fine with this form.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an event called "opening new record" as opposed to "open form"?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you set the default value of the control to Now() or Date(). The default value only applies to new records and once you complete any other field, the value will be assigned.

In this particular case, there is even an argument for setting the default value of the field in the table.

Please do not use Set Warnings: [What's the difference between DoCmd.SetWarnings and CurrentDB.Execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943)

Comment: As Homer said, "D'oh!" That was way too obvious. :-) I thought about that when I created the form, but chose not to because I thought I wanted it user initiated.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is still no one correctly answered why the code as posted does not work.

The REASON why is that you are using the on-open event.

Unlike .net and most systems access has a GREAT design in which you have two events occur when you an open form event (which can be canceled) and an on-load event.

This great design of Access means that code to test conditions and prevent the form load can be placed in the on-open event. If you look CLOSE you will see that the on-open even has a cancel. If you set cancel = true, then the FORM WILL NOT LOAD, AND WILL NOT DISPLAY.

So, you can test for no data, or for user rights or whatever, and huts cancel the form loading. If you can cancel the form loading, then it would make little sense to allow modifying the value of bound controls – as such all bound controls are READ ONLY.

You are NOT ALLOWED to change the values of BOUND controls in the on-open event. This is TOO soon and is by DESIGN and intention of the product.

So, testing of conditions to prevent the form load goes in on-open.

This thus suggests that setup of variables,, setup of controls, setting values of controls and your basic form startup code belongs in the ON-LOAD event. On-open is too soon.

And of Couse if your code is going to cancel a form load, then it is logical that all of your forms startup and setup code SHOULD NOT and does not need to run.

In summary

**On-open event:**

Can set cancel = true
Code goes here to test if you wish to prevent the form from loading and being seen by the user.

**On-LOAD event:**

All your startup code, setting of variables, setting of controls etc. is now recommended and possible.

And this simple design in Access ALSO means that as a developer you now know where to look for the code that will prevent and cancel the form load. Of course without this basic understanding of the difference and WHY two events exist in Access then the confusing of the poster and answers given becomes obvious.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a fan of moving to a new record on a form. There are too many data holes that can occur and you run into issues like yours.

I reccomend a blank, unbound form, with a textbox, calander conrol, number up down... etc for each of the fields that you want to add. This way you can type check each of the fields or do other checks against what you want.  Then, when the user is happy, then add the record with an insert query.

However, for the question that you asked. It looks like you are trying to assign a value to the bound field. Try assigning the value to the object the field is bound to.