# Disable default msgbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to disable the default msgbox from Access. This is my code,

```
Private Sub textRequiredDate_AfterUpdate()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

If Not IsDate(textRequiredDate.Value) Then
MsgBox "Please enter a date"

Else

End If

If textRequiredDate.Value < textOrderDate.Value Then
MsgBox "Required date must be after Order Date"
textOrderDate.SetFocus
textRequiredDate.SetFocus
textRequiredDate.Value = ""

Else

End If

End Sub
```

When I write letters on my date required I get the default MS access msgbox, I want to change it to my own message box.

Comment: Turning the warnings off is not usually a good idea, what are you seeing these msgbox's in relation to?

Comment: In what situation this happens?

Comment: I want to disable the msgbox from access and use my own msgbox. I have the code i wrote above

Comment: Good :) **Never** use DoCmd.SetWarnings False and having broken that rule, make sure you switch warnings back on. It does not do what you think it does, it is system wide and it will cause you endless problems. Swich warnings back on **now**! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957869/disable-default-msgbox-from-access

Comment: @Remou He he ^_^, that links us back to this question, you have provided the correct link on Andrey's answer though.

Comment: @MattDonnan ah well, it will be a nice stroll in the woods :D

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom error with the Form_Error event, for example this is for a Validation Rule error:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
      If DataErr = 2107 Then
         MsgBox "There was an error."
         Response = acDataErrContinue
      End If
End Sub
```

Other errors might be:

```
Private Sub Form_Error (DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
  Const REQUIREDFIELD_VIOLATION = 3314
  Const INPUTMASK_VIOLATION = 2279
  Const DUPLICATEKEY_VIOLATION = 3022
  If DataErr = DUPLICATEKEY_VIOLATION Then
     MsgBox "There was a key violation!"
     Response = acDataErrContinue
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings false
Application.DisplayAlerts = false
```

Comment: I've already tired this and still doesn't work. Would I need to state if the user enters letters into "Date Required" to enter a date??

Comment: **NEVER** set warnings false! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts` doesn't work in Access, only in Excel