# Can't write to a text file in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im trying to write to a text file using VBA. Here is my code:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'Delete all data from the source table
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tblSource;"

'Run query to fill it
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryFilltblSource"

' Declare a FileSystemObject.
Dim fso As FileSystemObject

' Create a FileSystemObject.
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' Declare a TextStream.
Dim stream As TextStream

' Create a TextStream. The true part overwrites a text file it it already exists
Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Target Folder", True)

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSource")

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do Until rst.EOF = True
    stream.WriteLine (rst!i)
    i = i + 1
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

stream.Close

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

The first error, I'm assuming I'm probably going to get another one, is "Permission Denied." I can't understand this one as I'm an Admin on this machine. I looked at the target folder and I have fill permissions to do what I want to it - but when I view its properties the box for "Read Only" is highlighted - why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Never use Set Warnings, it will turn around and bite you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be permitted to write to C root, so `C:\Target Folder\Atextfile.txt`

Consider using [TransferText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141567%28v=office.10%29.aspx):

```
 DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , tblSource, "c:\docs\output.txt", True
```

Note that you cannot say:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do Until rst.EOF = True
    stream.WriteLine (rst!i) <-- i is a record, not a field
    i = i + 1
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

You need

```
Do Until rst.EOF 
    For i=0 to rst.Fields.Count-1
       stream.WriteLine rst(i) ''or rst(i) & "" to avoid problems with Null
    Next
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: i sorted that one - always seems to be the way when i post it I solve it 5 minutes after - I neglected to give it a file name and it was trying to overwrite a directory - Now im getting an "Item not found in this collection error"

Comment: Why do you wish to go the long way around? The error is because you are referring to record numbers as if they were fields.

Comment: i tried what you suggested and got the error - "Invalid use of null" that was for the do loop. I went with the transfer approach and it worked a treat - Cheers Remou