# Object Required Error when executing SQL "Insert Into" Command in Access 2007 VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have used this method countless times, but I cannot for the life of me get this to work.  I keep tripping a run-time error "424". Any help is appreciated as `tblNormaAppend.[SORT SCORE].Value` shows as "empty" and so does `tblNormaAppend.SORT.Value`.  Both have values within the tables.  Thank you so much for any help.

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False


DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryDeleteNormaRadar"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryDeleteNormaAppend"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryFilterMFG"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryNormaAppend"


Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblNormaRadar (Attribute, Score) VALUES (" & tblNormaAppend.[SORT SCORE].Value & ", '" & tblNormaAppend.SORT.Value & "');"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it have dbo_ in front of it in the table tab of the object explorer?

Comment: Please do not use set warnings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute

Comment: This `tblNormaAppend.[SORT SCORE].Value` is not defined. Try `Me.[SORT SCORE].Value` if you are running in a form's module.

Comment: @Elias, I'm not quite sure what you mean.
@Remou, I removed set warnings, however there were no issues in the preceding lines of code anyway.  Also, I cannot use `me.` as I am not pulling from a form field.  I just do not understand why the objects are showing as "empty".

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me what `tblNormaAppend` is. In the context of a command button's code, it looks like a form control, but it sounds like you are referring to fields from a table, not values in the current record of the form.

If you just want to insert all of the values from one table into another, you can write straight (non-concatenated) SQL for this:

```
'add one record to tblNormaRadar for each record in tblNormaAppend
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblNormaRadar (Attribute, Score) SELECT [SORT SCORE], [Sort] FROM tblNormaAppend;"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

If you are aiming for something else, please describe more about `tblNormaAppend` and which values you want added to `tblNormaRadar`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The end goal is to create a radar chart based off of data from two specific fields in tblNormaAppend which houses scores from an audit. I have switched to trying to use straight SQL for this. 
        `INSERT INTO tblNormaRadar (ATTRIBUTE, SCORE)
    SELECT [SORT], [AvgOfSort Total]
    FROM qryFilterMFG
    WHERE GROUP_LEADER = [PUBLICREPORTS].[COMBO0]
    UNION ALL SELECT [SUSTAIN], [AvgOfSUSTAIN Total]
    FROM qryFilterMFG
    WHERE GROUP_LEADER = "Acevedo, Norma";`

Answer (score 0):

I use straight SQL.  I created multiple `INSERT INTO` queries since Access 2007 will not let you `UNION ALL` multiple fields within the same query.

Thanks for all the help.