# Can you turn off only some warnings in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, warnings, ms-access-2010

I'm building a front end for an Access database. My users don't want or need to see the "You about to insert X records" sort of messages that come up when you run an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE query.

The only way I've been able to find to turn these messages off programtically is `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` in VBA and then turning them on afterwards. However, this disables *all* warnings, and if the code errors before the `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` command, then they stay off, which can be anything from a nuisance to dangerous.

Is there any way of supressing **only** the SQL warnings in Access and leaving others (e.g. the "do you want to save this query" messages) intact?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11213943/2548

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run "action queries" with `Database.Execute` or `QueryDef.Execute` instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL`.

The `.Execute` methods do not trigger those confirmation messages, so no motivation to use `SetWarnings False` to suppress them.

Answer (score 2):

There is also this alternative, for those not wanting to write code [image: Access Options]

In Access Options > Advanced > Uncheck the required confirmation for the desired fields.

Comment: That's not suitable for my case, but otherwise completely valid. +1