# MS Access VBA loop through list

Tags: vba, ms-access

I think this should be simple, but I can't find the right way to do it.  I have a couple examples of the situation I'm trying to resolve, so I'll describe both.  I think they likely can be handled with the same solution, but if not, let me know. I'm trying to loop through a list of values, and run a SQL query for each one.  In one situation, the values are text, and in another, they are non-sequential integers.

Edited to add:  I should have said that the list of values is dynamic, it is coming from list of ID values selected in a combo box.  Right now, those are being stored as a comma delimited list in my variable named item_in_my_text_list and item_in_my_ID_list below.

Something like this:

```
item_in_my_text_list = "User-defined, mean, upper-bound"
For Each item_in_my_text_list(i)
    'run a query where i is part of the condition
    'I want to run the same query first the user-defined metric, then for the mean, then for the upper-bound
    'SQL should be "select metric, age, value into scenario where metric = 'user-defined'"
          SQL= "Select metric, age, value  into scenario WHERE metric = [i]
      DoCmd.SetWarnings False

          DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

          DoCmd.SetWarnings True

          SQL = ""
          rs.MoveNext

Loop
```

The other situation involves a non-sequential numeric list of ID values:

```
item_in_my_ID_list = "7, 9, 15, 88"
For Each item_in_my_ID_list(i)
    'run a query where i is part of the condition
    'I want to run the same query first for 7, then for 9, then 15, and so on
          SQL= "Update thistable set x = y where ID = " & [i]
      DoCmd.SetWarnings False

          DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

          DoCmd.SetWarnings True

          SQL = ""
          rs.MoveNext

Loop
```

What is the right syntax for setting up the loop?  When I try to use Split, it seems like it gives me the count of the items in the list, so when I try to use [i] as part of the query condition, I get, 1, 2, 3 (depending on the number of items in the list), rather than 'user-defined' or the correct ID value.

Edited to add my solution.  The suggestion from @mehow gave me what I needed to make this work.

```
Set db = CurrentDb
'Delete records for algorithms that aren't selected

    Dim DeleteSQL As String
    DeleteSQL = "Delete from Scenario WHERE ID not in (" & Me.ListSelect & ")"

    db.Execute DeleteSQL, dbFailOnError

    DeleteSQL = ""

'for each of the IDs selected, copy the whole scenario
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(Me.ListSelect, ","))
    'find the records from the scenario table, and copy them for the "upper bound"
    SQL = "insert into scenario (a, b, c)"
    SQL = SQL & " SELECT a, b, c
    SQL = SQL & " FROM Scenario "
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE Scenario.Id= " & Trim(Split(Me.ListSelect, ",")(i)) 

    db.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError
    SQL = ""

    'reset user-defined values for both mean and upper bound
    Dim allMetrics As String
    allMetrics = "Central tendency, Upper bounding"

    Dim thisMetric As Long
    For thisMetric = 0 To UBound(Split(allMetrics, ","))
         Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
         Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Parameter FROM AllParameters WHERE Id= " & Trim(Split(Me.ListSelect, ",")(i)))

         Dim DefaultSQL As String
         If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
             Do Until rs.EOF = True
                DefaultSQL = "UPDATE defaults LEFT JOIN scenario ON defaults.Age = Scenario.Age SET Scenario." & rs("Parameter") & " = [defaults].[Value] "
                DefaultSQL = DefaultSQL & " WHERE defaults.ID =" & Trim(Split(Me.ListSelect, ",")(i))
                DefaultSQL = DefaultSQL & " And defaults.metric = '" & Trim(Split(allMetrics, ",")(thisMetric)) & "'"


                db.Execute DefaultSQL, dbFailOnError
                DefaultSQL = ""
                rs.MoveNext
             Loop

         End If

         rs.Close
         Set rs = Nothing
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Please do not use SetWarnings and RunSQL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943

Comment: @Remou, thanks for the link.  I'm glad to have a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the below is the syntax you may be looking for

```
Sub Main()

    Dim myList As String
    myList = "7, 9, 15, 88"

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(myList, ","))
        SQL = "Select metric, age, value  into scenario " & _
              "WHERE metric = " & Trim(Split(myList, ",")(i))
        ' the rest of your code...
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked for me.  The part I was missing when I was trying to use the Split function before was the syntax for referencing the right term within the list -- Trim(Split(myList, ",")(i)).

Answer (score 4):

`For Each i In VBA.Split(item_in_my_ID_list, ",")` is one way. `i` is a string type.

You might have to use `VBA.Trim(i)` to cater for spaces between the commas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an array and then loop through it.

```
Dim str(2) As String
Dim i as Integer

str = Array("one", "two", "three")

For i = 0 To UBound(str)
    ...str(i)


Next
```

Comment: Awesome.  This makes sense.  So to use the variable that contains my comma delimited list, the syntax would be something like 'Dim str(2) As String
Dim i as Integer

str = Array(myvariable)

For i = 0 To UBound(str)
    ...str(i)' @E Mett


Next

Comment: An array is a list of variables so use separate variables such as: `str= Array("User-defined", "mean", "upper-bound")`