# 2-part AfterUpdate() subroutine not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have 2 subroutines below.

I have a form that gets updated by the end-user. Upon updating the `Me.ID` field in the form, it fires the sub `ID_AfterUpdate`. This part is successful.

I then want to trigger an SQL update query `updateReportFlag` that tags that record with a specific value. This part is not working. Can someone tell me why? I am inspecting the `Input_Table.[ReportFlag]` field after the initial update and it is NULL, so in theory the 2nd sub should work.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub ID_AfterUpdate()
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Customer.[Customer Name] " _
                        & "FROM Customer " _
                        & "WHERE Customer.[ID] = '" & Me.ID & "'")

If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
    Me.txtCustomerName = rs![Customer Name]
    updateReportFlag ' TRIGGERS THE UPDATE IN THE NEXT SUBROUTINE
Else
    MsgBox ("Invalid ID")
End If

End Sub


Private Sub updateReportFlag()

    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Input_Table " _
                & "SET Input_Table.[ReportFlag] = ""Report1"" " _
                & "WHERE Input_Table.[ReportFlag] IS NULL "
End Sub
```

**Edit** - here is the code that serves as the form's Record Source. Notice how it is not SELECTing the Input_Table.[ReportFlag]) field, but the table contains it. This is why my UPDATE query in `sub updateReportFlag` does not update the form and instead updates the table that feeds the form. Not sure if this is relevant.

```
SELECT Input_Table.[ID], Input_Table.[Customer Name] FROM Input_Table
WHERE (((Input_Table.[ReportFlag])="Report1"));
```

**Edit 2** - i was playing around with this and noticed that the query works if you enter more than one `Me.ID` value. After the first entry, nothing gets updated. After the 2nd entry, the first entry gets updated. It seems like the record does not actually get committed to the table before the UPDATE query gets triggered. Is there some way to get the record to commit before running the UPDATE query?

Comment: Any errors? Have you stepped through the code? BTW it is nearly alway better to separate the sql string from the command and to use .Execute against an instance of the db http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943

Comment: No errors. I changed `updateReportFlag` to `Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError` like you suggested, but it is still not executing the update. I stepped through the code and it is hitting all necessary code blocks. One thing I did not mention yesterday was that the form uses a query to display its data - please see edit in the main post. Although I don't see why this would be relevant, since it is hitting the table I am running the query against in the sub `updateReportFlag`

Comment: Please see Edit 2 - i found some weird behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The record that had been created in the destination table was not being committed until after the `CDL_AfterUpdate` sub was done executing. Since the `updateReportFlag` was being called from the `CDL_AfterUpdate` sub, the record it was targeting in the UPDATE was not yet committed, so it couldn't find records to update.

I added the following code block, which forced the record to be committed before the `updateReportFlag` sub was called:

```
If Me.Dirty Then
    Me.Dirty = False
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate your time spent reviewing.