# Show message box when user presses "NO"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've the following code which deletes a all data from a table in access. I however also would like ot show a message box saying "ok you didn't delete anthing when the user presses NO when the screen pops up with "Are you sure....".

Does anybody know how I can create thing like this?

```
Public Function DeleteDataSAP()

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tb_Organisatiestructuur"

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub main()

    Dim retval
    retval = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2)

    If retval = vbYes Then
        DeleteDataSAP
    ElseIf retval = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "ok you didn't delete anthing "
    End If
End Sub
```

```
 Public Function DeleteDataSAP()

        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tb_Organisatiestructuur"

    End Function
```

Comment: Please do not use RunSQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943