# Enable confirmation(warning) messages in Access app

Tags: c#, ms-access, interop

We have a problem, that programmatically created and showed Access App don't show any confirmation messages.

For example, when executed delete query.

This is used code. Any playing with usage of other values instead of 'true' not helped.

```
var instance = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application()
instance.Visible = true;
var s = instance.GetOption("Confirm Action Queries");
var t = instance.GetOption("Confirm Document Deletions");
var n = instance.GetOption("Confirm Record Changes");
instance.SetOption("Confirm Action Queries", true);
instance.SetOption("Confirm Document Deletions", true);
instance.SetOption("Confirm Record Changes", true);
instance.OpenCurrentDatabase(documentFile);
instance.DoCmd.SetWarnings(true);
```

But it's enough to go in open Access app to File->Options and click Cancel in Options dialog for starting confirmation messages correct showing.

Do you have any idea how to enable programmatically confirmation/warning messages?

Here you could found [Sample app](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B018hboGnS4tc3U4Q3lqMmNxVkE/edit?usp=sharing).
For reproduce problem:

1. at All Access Objects -> Queries -> girls - right mouse click -> Design view
2. Go to Jahr column, put in Criteria - ">1900"
3. In Query tools (Design) Tab -> Select Delete query type.
4. Click on Run -> any messages
5. Go to File->Options, click on Cancel. click Run again - message should appear.

Comment: Please do not use SetWarnings, it is very dangerous, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943 Just edit any Access file to turn warnings back on and never touch them again.

Comment: Thanks, but we tried it without SetWarnings - same result

Answer (score 0):

Using of

```
instance.UserControl = true
```

solved this problem