# Forcing a clean close of forms before access quit

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 database which is using a form `frmTimeKeeper` to keep track of the users in the database. The form itsself has a width of 0 so it cannot be seen. It is the first form opened when the database opens and closes when access closes. It has 2 events, open and close:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tblUserLogs SET timeOut=#" & Date & " " & time() & "# WHERE id=" & UserLogID
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox "time keeper close"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblUserLogs(user, timeIn) VALUES ('" & Environ("Username") & "',#" & Date & " " & time() & "#)"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblUserLogs WHERE user='" & Environ("Username") & "' AND timeOut IS NULL ORDER BY id DESC")
    UserLogID = rst(0)

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLogin"
End Sub
```

`UserLogID` is a global varriable

Essentially the form opens (When the db opens) and writes to `tblUserLogs` the username and the date time. Then when the database is closed the close sub writes to that same record using `UserLogID` to ensure its the right record. And it works great until I use a button on another form that runs the command `DoCmd.Quit acQuitPrompt` which closes the DB. When this happens There is no `timeOut` inputted for that record. I have been able to get a msgbox to appear from the `Form_Close` event in frmTimeKeeper if it is before the SQL statement but not when it is after the SQL statement. Is there a way I can make all the other forms close cleanly before quiting Access?

`tblUserLogs` for reference:

```
ID    user      timeIn                          timeOut
2   Evan      7/29/2014 3:41:58 PM              7/29/2014 3:42:11 PM
3   Evan      7/29/2014 3:42:50 PM              7/29/2014 3:42:57 PM
4   Evan      7/29/2014 3:43:10 PM              7/29/2014 3:43:22 PM
5   J         7/29/2014 3:45:06 PM              7/29/2014 3:46:35 PM
6   J         7/29/2014 3:46:57 PM              7/29/2014 3:47:20 PM
7   Evan      7/30/2014 7:16:43 AM              7/30/2014 7:17:49 AM
8   Evan      7/30/2014 7:36:56 AM              7/30/2014 7:38:56 AM
9   Evan      7/30/2014 10:42:36 AM             7/30/2014 10:42:42 AM
10  Evan      7/30/2014 10:51:56 AM             7/30/2014 10:52:06 AM
11  Evan      7/30/2014 10:55:07 AM 
12  Evan      7/30/2014 11:05:25 AM             7/30/2014 11:05:42 AM
13  Evan      7/30/2014 11:06:00 AM 
14  Evan      7/30/2014 11:07:20 AM 
15  Evan      7/30/2014 11:08:21 AM 
16  Evan      7/30/2014 11:14:42 AM 
17  Evan      7/30/2014 11:17:50 AM             7/30/2014 11:18:02 AM
18  Evan      7/30/2014 11:19:28 AM 
19  Evan      7/30/2014 11:23:06 AM             7/30/2014 11:23:08 AM
20  Evan      7/30/2014 11:23:55 AM             7/30/2014 11:24:22 AM
```

The missing `timeOut` values are because of this error

Thanks

Comment: You are making some horrible mistakes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute

Comment: Noted and changed, I am going to have to tell my boss/mentor about this because he showed it to me... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click of the button that calls the DoCmd.Quit manually close the timeKeeper form. Like,

```
Private Sub yourOtherButtonName_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_TimeKeeper"
    DoCmd.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: I just figured this out and was posting it then you beat me to it. Yes this works exactly as I wanted it to, Thanks

Comment: You did not mention the horrible mistakes.

Comment: Are you aware of how bad using Set Warnings is?