# using the CDate function together with the Now() function

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Using the now function i would like to post the date but reformatted in yyyy/mm/dd.  Below is my attempt (with bad syntax)

```
st_sql = "UPDATE[tblPerformanceTrackingMaster02]INNER JOIN[tblValueAdds]ON[tblPerformanceTrackingMaster02].[ID_ValueAddWaste]=[tblValueAdds].[ID_ValueAdd]SET[tblPerformanceTrackingMaster02].[Effective_Date]=now(CDate(Format([tblPerformanceTrackingMaster02].[Effective_date], ""yyyy/mm/dd"")))where[tblPerformanceTrackingMaster02].[Effective_Date]is null"
        Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```

Comment: You do not seem to understand MS Access dates, they are all numbers, there is no need to mess about unless you are storing strings. Please do not use DoCmd.RunSQL ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943 )

Comment: Why not DoCmd.RunSQL ?  (its the only way i know to execute my SQL queries)

Comment: Please see the link in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The follwoing delivers the desired result:

```
st_sql = "UPDATE[tblPerformanceTrackingMaster02]INNER JOIN[tblValueAdds]ON[tblPerformanceTrackingMaster02].[ID_ValueAddWaste]=[tblValueAdds].[ID_ValueAdd]SET[tblPerformanceTrackingMaster02].[Effective_Date]=CDate(Format((now()),""yyyy/mm/dd""))where[tblPerformanceTrackingMaster02].[Effective_Date]is null"
        Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```

Comment: I am afraid that this shows a lack of understanding of dates.

Comment: yes that is very possible. What alternative is available?