# MS ACCESS - Inserting into table from another table with variable to a field

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSRET INTO Table1 SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table2"
```

It works perfectly to copy from Table2 to Table1.  I need to insert a variable to Table1 on each insertion.  It is not constant.  It chanages on each RunSQL.

StringVar is the variable.  How should I do it? Something like below.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSRET INTO Table1 SELECT Field1, Field2 '" & StringVar & "' AS Filed3 FROM Table2"
```

Comment: You need a comma before the value and you should list the columns in the `insert` statement.

Comment: Please avoid RunSQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute  You need to keep an eye on spelling as well.

Comment: It works by DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO table1 SELECT field1, field2, '" & StringVar & "' AS field3 FROM table2".  Both tables have same field name and columns are not required.