# Run-time error '91' Object variable not set

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

My code works well, but when I reopen the database I am getting the following error; anybody know how may I fix this issue? Once I open the database, and run the code few times I no longer get the error.

**Run-time error '91' Object variable not set**

```
Sub ImportAllTables_New_Click()
Dim dt As Date
    dt = Now() 'save current single timestamp for later use

 DoCmd.SetWarnings False

On Error GoTo errHandler

Call LoadData("C:\Idea Attributes\tbl_IdeasITAssumptions.xlsm", "TempIdeasITAssumptions", "Qry_IdeasITAssumptions", "Qry_AppendIdeasITAssumptions")
Call LoadData("C:\Idea Attributes\tbl_IdeasDependencies.xlsm", "TempIdeasDependencies", "Qry_IdeasDependencies", "Qry_AppendIdeasDependencies")
Call LoadData("C:\Idea Attributes\tbl_IdeasImpactedPlan.xlsm", "TempIdeasImpactedPlan", "Qry_IdeasImpactedPlan", "Qry_AppendIdeasImpactedPlan")
Call LoadData("C:\Idea Attributes\tbl_IdeasImpactedSubsidiaries.xlsm", "TempIdeasImpactedSubsidiaries", "Qry_IdeasImpactedSubsidiaries", "Qry_AppendIdeasImpactedSubsidiaries")
Call LoadData("C:\Idea Attributes\tbl_IdeasLOB.xlsm", "TempIdeasLOB", "Qry_IdeasLOB", "Qry_AppendIdeasLOB")
Call LoadData("C:\Idea Attributes\tbl_IdeasPhaseGate.xlsm", "TempIdeasPhaseGate", "Qry_IdeasPhaseGate", "Qry_AppendIdeasPhaseGate")
Call LoadData("C:\Idea Attributes\tbl_IdeasDataExtractMain.xlsm", "TempIdeasDataExtractMain", "Qry_IdeasDataExtractMain", "Qry_AppendIdeasDataExtractMain")

 'update all [Load_date] that are greater than  the timestamp captured before you started import




DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [tbl_IdeasITAssumptions] set [Load_Date] = #" & dt & "# where [Load_Date]  > #" & dt & "#"
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [tbl_IdeasDependencies] set [Load_Date] = #" & dt & "# where [Load_Date]  > #" & dt & "#"
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [tbl_IdeasImpactedPlan] set [Load_Date] = #" & dt & "# where [Load_Date]  > #" & dt & "#"
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [tbl_IdeasImpactedSubsidiaries] set [Load_Date] = #" & dt & "# where [Load_Date]  > #" & dt & "#"
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [tbl_IdeasLOB] set [Load_Date] = #" & dt & "# where [Load_Date] > #" & dt & "#"
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [tbl_IdeasPhaseGate] set [Load_Date] = #" & dt & "# where [Load_Date]  > #" & dt & "#"
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [tbl_IdeasDataExtractMain] set [Load_Date] = #" & dt & "# where [Load_Date]  > #" & dt & "#"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox ("All Tables has been Imported")

errHandler:
  MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & " in " & _
   VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule, vbOKOnly, "Error"

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error? I'm guessing that it is `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`. If not,  you might want to turn the error handling off and find the actual point of failure.  Where does that variable get its value from? I'm guessing that some initialization code needs to be rerun before you invoke this sub.

Comment: Please get rid of setwarnings altogether, they are fatal and system wide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943

Comment: BTW that error is nearly always due to missing set with a object variable.

Comment: Yes I started getting it , once I added DoCmd.SetWarnings False, But what else I can use to, I don't want the user to click "Ok"  10-12 times

Comment: Check out my link above. You can use Execute: `Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError`

Comment: so something like this: Set db = CurrebtDB db.Execute sSQL "UPDATE [tbl_IdeasITAssumptions] set [Load_Date] = #" & dt & "# where [Load_Date]  > #" & dt & "#"          dbFailOnError

Comment: You might like to look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834805.aspx

Comment: Yes, if there are a few commas in there. You only need to set db once, and you can get records affected if you want. sSQL is a reference to the sql statement, so skip it if you are giving the statement itself.

Comment: See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243015(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Ok I am getting different error now I tried this Set db = CurrentDB Db.Execute "UPDATE [tbl_IdeasITAssumptions] set [Load_Date] = #" & dt & "# where [Load_Date]  > #" & dt & "#"       tHE ERROR says Invalid use of property

Comment: Perhaps you would like to edit your post to include your current code? Comments are a little limited.

Comment: I updated the code, thanks!

Comment: dbFailOnError goes after each statement, not where you have it. So: `db.Execute sqlstatementhere, dbFailOnError`

Comment: Thanks that worked,  sorry to keep bothering you, but I still have to press "yes" for all my Call LoadData("C:\Idea Attributes\tbl_IdeasDat..... anyway I can have system skip those, or is it possible to chage those into sql execute statements too?

Comment: What does loaddata do? Please post the code.

Comment: Done! I have updated the code

Comment: It was not a good idea to delete your original question. The problem is here `DoCmd.OpenQuery Qry_Append, acViewNormal`. You can convert this query to an Execute. Queries can be executed.

Comment: Sure I have the original question and I will place that back:
So to change this DoCmd.OpenQuery Qry_Append, acViewNormal
Should I write  Db.Execute “OpenQuery Qry_Append, acViewNormal”

Comment: n/m I fixed it : Db.Execute Qry_Append, acViewNormal........Thanks  a LOT FOR YOUR HELP!!!

Comment: Replace acViewNormal, with dbFailOnError. What you have is not safe. acViewNormal = 0; dbfailonerror = 128. These are built-in constants, do not mess with them.

Comment: Got it thanks I changed it to  Db.Execute Qry_Append, dbFailOnError