# Run-time error '424'

Tags: ms-access

**Requirement:**

I'm looking to run a query when a specific control is `Null`.

However I see this error every time:

**Error:**

> "object required"

Form is called `PLanningForm`, control which is `Null` is `OrigRTL`.

Any help gratefully appreciated!

**Code:**

```
If Me.OrigRTL.Value Is Null Then

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "OrigDates"
Me.Refresh
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Else
DoCmd.GoToControl "OrigRtL"

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not use set warings ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943 )

Comment: You cannot go to a control that has focus. You should always report the line that gives the error. Step through the code and find it.